# SSRS: - Across then down Columns in Child groups

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2012

I've looked around and haven't found anything on having a dataset display Across then Down in SSRS - likely using wrong search parameters.

What I am trying to accomplish is a report that is separated into Groups by a ParentGroup (Property), Child group (Type), Grandchild group (@week).  In each @week group I will have several two tuple dataset (person, person-code).  Getting each group to display, sort, hide, color coordinate, etc have been straightforward.  But I need each week to display the name:name-code to display left to right(lrt\across) 3-4 lined up columns and then down.  I am only able to do it down and across - using columns. This is simple in Crystal but I need to convert this to SSRS.  I have read something on using a MOD with lists, but I must not understand it correctly.  The "Ideal Layout" show how I would like to show this in 3 columns  - again going ATD.
Once I can figure this out it will expand to another report that would have a dynamic # of columns per group based on an even distribution, based on the longest result int a dataset

Thank you in advance for any direction.

I've tried following from this thread ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825548/ssrs-limit-fixed-number-of-columns-in-matrix-within-a-tablix-issue-in-sorting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825548/ssrs-limit-fixed-number-of-columns-in-matrix-within-a-tablix-issue-in-sorting)

Any help on where to look or options would be greatly appreciated.

There is a link to the Crystal layout and output result desired here [Ideal Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU02C.png)
[Crystal Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrkdP.png)

Comment: I think I've done something like this. Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833487/ssrs-report-badges/68837635#68837635 like what you want? Use a parameter for the **2** columns so you can adjust as needed.